# Problem to send data toJava spring client API multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring, request, client

I have created Java service endpoint

```
   @RequestMapping(path = "/create", method = POST,   
           consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},   
           produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)  
    public ResponseEntity<RecordData> createRecord(Authentication auth, Locale locale,  
           @RequestPart("data") @Valid CreateRecordRequest dataBody,  
           @RequestPart("file") List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) throws ParseException {
```

or

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/create", 
           consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
           produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<RecordData> createRecord(Authentication auth, Locale locale,
           @RequestPart(value = "data") @Valid CreateDraftRecordRequest dataBody,
           @RequestPart(value = "file") List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) throws ParseException {
```

Invoking service using SoapUI a got just 400 and code is not executed = no log entry, no breakpoint activated
[image: SoapUI request]

or using curl

```
$ curl -v --location "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/create" --header "Cookie: " 
--form "data=\"{\"files\": {\"enabled\": true},\"metadata\": {}}\";type=application/json" 
--form 'file=@"_test.txt"'
```

with response

```
> POST /api/v1/create HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 339
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------63b3d3729b33a350
>
} [339 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Security-Policy: frame-src: 'none'
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 18 May 2023 06:39:55 GMT
< Connection: close
<
100   339    0     0  100   339      0    650 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   651
* Closing connection 0
```

What should I change to send data/files correctly

Comment: I think you are passing file inside the JSON body instead of passing it in the multipart section.